# Check if some query is undefined and define a callback in that case

Tags: node.js, influxdb

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
var query = 'select max(count) from ' + series +
    ' where value = \'' + search + '\'';

if (db.query(query, callback) !== undefined) {

    return callback;
} else {

    return callback = [{
        name: series,
        columns: ['time', 'max'],
        points: [
            [0, 0]
        ]
    }];
}
```

I'm trying to verify if that query is undefined or the element searched doesn't exist in the influxdb, and then arm a callback just like if the element exist, the if sentence works, but the else return an empty array

The db parameter is where are the data base configurations.

**EDIT:**

Thanks Osukaa for your answe. I try what you sugest but don't have response. Here is the complete function with your changes:

```
var counter = function (config, callback) {

var count = 'select max(count) from ' + series + ' where value = \'' + search + '\'';

db.query(count, function (err, res) {
  if(err) return err;

  if(res.length == 0){
    return [{
      name: series,
      columns: ['time', 'max'],
      points: [
        [0, 0]
      ]
    }];
  }else{
    return res;
  }

});   
};
```

The console.log shows an empty array.

**EDIT 2:**

Thanks @Osukaa, unfortunately that don't work, this is the error that returns:

Debug: handler, error 
    {"msec":395.7593630000483,"error":"Couldn't find series: items.type.updated"}
Debug: internal, error 
    Error: Couldn't find series: items.type.updated

**EDIT 3:**

I've solved the problem when try to create a series. When the series don't exist, show this error 'Error Couldn't find series [series name]', so I put this code in the error code:

```
db.query(qCount, function(err, res) {

    if (err) {

        if (err == 'Error: Couldn\'t find series: ' + name.series) {

            res = newSeries;
            return callback(null, res);
        } else {

            return callback(err);
        }
    } else {

        if (res.length !== 0) {

            return callback(null, res);
        } else {

            res = newSeries;
            return callback(null, res);
        }
    }
});
```

When the error is equal to 'Error: Couldn\'t find series: ' + name.series, I pass the values to create them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asynchronous code doesn't work like that. When the `db.query` is completed it will automatically execute the `callback` code. It isn't necessary for you to do a `return callback`. Instead you could try something like this:

```
db.query('select max(count) from ' + series +
' where value = \'' + search + '\'' + ';', function (err, res) {
  if(err) return err;

  if(res.length == 0){
    return [{
      name: series,
      columns: ['time', 'max'],
      points: [
        [0, 0]
      ]
    }];
  }else{
    return res;
  }

});
```

*EDIT*

First you make the `GET` to obtain the count

```
request.get('/itemCount')
.query({value: value.type})
.end(function(err, res) {
  if (err) {
    reply(err);
  } else {
    countElemnts(res.body[0].count);
  }
});
```

So the server goes to the route and executes the handler:

```
server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/itemCount',
  handler: function(request, reply) {
    events.selectCount({
      series: 'value.type',
      search: request.url.query.value
    }, function onSuccess(err, data) {      
      if (err) {
        reply(err);
      } else {
        var result = {};
        if (data.length !== 0) {
          result = data[0].points.map(function(element) {
            return {
              count: element[1] + 1
            };
          });
          reply(null, result);
        } else {
          reply(null, data);
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Which itself calls the `selectCount` function to obtain the number *(I updated the `callback` to return `(null,res)`)*

```
var selectCount = function(config, callback) {

  var qCount = 'select max(count) from ' + config.series +
  ' where itemType = \'' + config.search + '\'';

  db.query(qCount, function(err, res) {  
    if (err) {
      return callback(err);
    }else{
      if (res !== undefined) {
        return callback(null,res[0]);
      }else{
        var res = [{
          name: config.series,
          columns: ['time', 'count'],
          points: [
            [0, 0]
          ]
        }];
        return callback(null,res);
      }
    }
  });
};
```

And when the callbacks finish, it should execute `countElements`:

```
var countElemnts = function(count) {
  superagent
  .post(config.eventsApiUrl)
  .type('json')
  .send({
    name: 'items.type.updated',
    data: {
      id: request.params.id,
      itemType: item.itemType,
      count: count
    }
  })
  .end(function() {
    reply({
      message: 'Item actualizado'
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Now if the series does not exist give me the error but don't create de series. What can be happening? This is the error: {"msec":30.899682998657227,"error":"Couldn't find series: series.updated"}

Comment: Where is your console.log where it doesn't show anything? is something like `console.log(counter)` ?

Comment: I solved that the problem, now is if the series don't exist gives me the error but don't create the series. Here is a link to google groups where is the complete code that i use: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=es-419#!topic/influxdb/XnpA0t84ywQ

Comment: @diego it could be that you're not returning the `selectCount` callback with `callback(null,res)`. I updated my answer with your complete code.

Comment: thanks for your reply, unfortunately in the first post is the error that gave me.

Comment: The error is happening in another place, not really until the `console.log` call. Add more `console.log` through your code

Comment: thanks for your replies helps me a lot. I've solved the problem when the series don't exist, it is on the original post in edit 3. Thanks again for your time.